# typescript file recognized as MPEG-2 ts file

Tags: typescript

I have a problem. I created a .ts file but my windows 7 computer takes it as an MPEG-2 ts file, not a typescript file. How do I solve this?

Comment: one method would be open properties of the file and change the open with to your editor.

Comment: This isn't a TypeScript issue. It is just a collision/overloading of file extensions. @jaibalaji said, change the default associated program in windows to an IDE/text editor.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1464304/4522 for registry settings to make Windows recognise .ts files as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by downloading a typescript package via npm